# What is the easiest UML diagram to model?

Tags: deployment, localhost, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I am currently implementing an app and I am on the design stages at the moment. I know for a fact that the deployment diagram is fairly easy to model and can be done in the space of 2 hours.

Likewise, what are some of the easiest UML diagrams to model - i.e ones that don't require much effort and time. I am asking as I have a tight schedule in terms of other commitments and I want to get all the same bits and bobs out of the way

Also, what is the difference between a `localhost` server - i.e one on your laptop, and a normal `remote` server? I just need to know so that I can model my `deployment` diagram.

Thanks

Comment: What has the localhost question to do with the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that question is complete nonsense. You never model a diagram. You model a model and show it to humans by means of diagrams. So to answer your question: The easiest one is one that shows nothing at all (take any possible diagram you like). That way you also show nothing. If you want to show something, you need to take the effort to compose the diagram(s).

Maybe you think over your question.

P.S. Have you ever had a homework at school to describe a picture? It's analogous: if you just say "it's paint inside a rectangle frame" then it's a description. But a poor one. You can go on an say "There's a face of a person" (if it's a portrait). That would say a bit more, but you see that the essence is hard to find. IIRC Euklid has been asked if there's a king's way to mathematics. You probably know his answer.

Comment: Okay then. Sorry if the question was complete nonsense - I will know where to ask these questions next time!

Comment: You can ask questions here, but not at a level of "how can I get rid of my homework without effort?".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Cons.
The answer of course is none as that is the quickest. However this is feeling like a class assignment so i will guess that you should probably do a class diagram and a deployment diagram.
Often if you have to describe the chat between two objects between two machines, lots of other diagram types come in. I like activity diagrams with swimlanes for that.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a use case diagram, with one activity diagram per use case.  I also use a class diagram.  Those are probably the fundamentally necessary diagrams.  I only use a deployment diagram if the deployment is fairly complex.

The reason that you're getting some negative feedback is that you appear to be asking how to make a good impression rather than how to do the job right.  If your priority is to do diagrams with a minimum of effort rather than to create useful diagrams, the easiest thing is not to do them at all.  Otherwise, use diagrams to explain the model in the simplest way possible.